# Domain events are customer defined, not hard-coded

Tags: domain-driven-design, saas, domain-events

Requirements for our SaaS product are to build a domain layer where any attribute or combination of attributes that are changed could trigger a domain event - and subsequently kick off a custom process, or notification.

So, I am hesitant to add tons of code to the domain layer that kicks off tons of DomainEvent objects which may not make sense to many tenants.

Each tenant will have the ability to (through a UI screen):
1. define which attributes they care about (e.g. "amount") and why (e.g. amount is now greater than $100)
2. define what happens when they change (e.g. kick off an approval process)

This seems like a business rules engine integration to me along with a BPMS.  Does anyone have thoughts on a more lighter-weight framework or solution to this?

Comment: Your problem seems quite easy to solve with low-level events such as `AttributeChanged`. If the event publisher uses a map to organize handlers by event types the cost of publishing one that has no handlers should be negligible. Most strategies that you will put in place to avoid invoking an event when it's not necessary will require extra processing anyway and you might just end up with accidental complexity with no performance benefits.

If you really want your code to be adaptive so that it's almost re-writing itself  I would look towards using some kind of decorators to form a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You could publish a generic event that has its constraints/specification defined against a unique `Name`.  Let's call the event `SpecificationEvent`.  Perhaps you would have a `SpecificationEventService` that can check you domain objects that implement a `ISpecificationValueProvider` and return a populated event that you could publish:

```
public interface ISpecificationEventValueProvider
{
    object GetValue(string name);
}

public class SpecificationEventService
{
    IEnumerable<SpecificationEvent> FindEvents(ISpecificationEventValueProvider provider);
}

public class SpecificationEvent
{
    private List<SpecificationEventValue> _values;

    public string Name ( get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<ISpecificationEventValue> Values
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<ISpecificationEventValue>(_values); }
    }  
}

public class SpecificationEventValue
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public SpecificationEventValue(string name, object value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

So you would define the custom events in some store.  Possibly from some front-end that is used to defined the constraints that constitute the event.  The `SpecificationEventService` would use that definition to determine whether the candidate object conforms to the requirements and then returns the event with the populated values that you can then publish.

The custom code could be registered in an endpoint where you handle the generic `SpecificationEvent`.  Each of the custom handlers can be handed the event for handling but only the handler that determines that the event is valid for *it* will perform any real processing.

Hope that makes sense.  I just typed this up so it is not production-level code and you could investigate the use of generics for the `object` :)

Comment: I'm not convinced that would perform better than always trigger an event like `AttributeChanged` and then have additional handlers to conditionally publish more explicit events. Depending on the publisher implementation, publishing an event with no handlers should have a very low cost.